# problem pushing to GitHub from a remote computer over SSH

Tags: github, ssh, push, remote-access

As we are all working from home, I tried to set up an SSH environment that I can edit my code on my workstation in or lab. The process went smoothly and I am able to edit and run my code on my remote workstation. I can also easily stage and commit the changes over SSH. But, when it comes to pushing the commits to GitHub, `git push` struggles.

I can push easily in the command line when I am connected to the remote workstation via RDP, but when I am connected via SSH, `git push` freezes and never gets back. My local and remote machines are using Windows 10. I highly appreciate your help and input.

PS: I attached a screenshot of the successful push via RDP and an unsuccessful one via SSH .
[image: screenshot of the successful push via RDP and an unsuccessful one via SSH].